# Unable to pythonically delete dataset.columns.name

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe

Working with a Panda Series that looks like this, where `date_block_num` doesn't count for a column I can drop with `df.drop()`

My table looks like this:

```
date_block_num   0     1    2    3    4    5   ...   27   28   29   30   31   32
0               0.0  31.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
1               0.0  11.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
2               6.0  10.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
3               3.0   3.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
4               1.0  14.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
```

I really need to delete `date_block_num`

To reconfirm that is the name associated with my columns, I tried `dataset.columns` That then gave me `Index([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33], dtype='object', name='date_block_num')`

But I am at a loss for how to get rid of the column associated with date_block_num

Comment: ```date_block_num``` is an index? You want to eliminate index column?

Comment: Did you do something like pandas.Index.rename to rename the index to "date_block_num"?

Comment: I think that is what I need to do, because my model.fit gives me an issue with ```fit() got multiple values for argument 'epochs'``` and my intuition said this is the right way

Comment: if the `.fit()` function said for multiple values for `epochs`, may be it *did* get multiple values. Check the parameters in your `.fit()` function to see if you are passing the `epochs` parameter multiple times

Comment: @Mr.JohnnyDoe can you please elaborate what you are exactly trying to do with the dataframe, especially the transformation?

Comment: It just comes down to that. When I do ```fit(X_train,y_train,X_test,y_test)``` I get a ```The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().``` The moment I put ```'epochs'``` I get the ```fit() got multiple values for argument epochs```

Answer (score 1):

"date_block_num" is index, if you want to delete it you can do it as follow:

```
df.reset_index().drop(["date_block_num"], axis=1)
```

Comment: @SoumojitGhosh I thought Mr. Johnny Doe would like to delete the "date_block_num" as a column